# how to create excel file in ios

Tags: objective-c, excel, ios7

I am tring to create a excel file in IOS, I manage to do this simple creating our string and writing it to a file with extention .csv, This fine but the problem is that all the data is comming on a single cell. Can any help me out with some code.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452962/how-to-write-array-data-into-excel-file-csv-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1):

You can just insert a comma in the string between all seperate columns and a newline for every row, then write it CSV and it'll work.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks Sjors, I already tried  that but it is not working the write way, If I insert comma and open it in Numbers, then it is working fine, but If i open it in open offce, it is not woring as should be. Every single space is going to new column.